# Incorrect positioning node on an arc

Tags: positioning, labels, arc

I want to positioning a node with label `\gamma` on an arc, but the way that usually I use produces incorrect positioning: the label is placed too far from the curve that I draw. Here there is my code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a4paper, top=2cm, bottom=3cm, left=2.5cm, right=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{tikz,tikz-3dplot}  
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,decorations.markings,intersections,patterns,shadings,calc,shapes,positioning,  pgfplots.fillbetween, shapes.geometric}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\definecolor{azz}{RGB}{175,238,238}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[>=latex,
]
\newcommand\xmi{-1.2};
\newcommand\xma{1.2};
\newcommand\yma{1.2};
\newcommand{\radi}{1};
  \begin{axis}[
    clip=false,
    width=16cm,
    axis equal image,
    xmin=\xmi, xmax=\xma,
    ymin=\xmi, ymax=\xma,
    axis lines=middle,
    no markers,
    xtick={0},
    ytick={0},
    xticklabels={,,},
    yticklabels={,,},
    extra x ticks={0},
    extra x tick style={xticklabel style={anchor=north east}},
    extra x tick label={\Large $0$},
    xlabel={\Large $\mathbb{R}$},
    ylabel={\Large $i \mathbb{R}$},
    axis on top
    ]
  \draw[fill=azz!100!white, opacity=0.7] (0,0) circle (\radi) ;
\draw[line width=2pt] (\radi,0)   arc[start angle=0,end angle=90,radius=\radi] node[pos=0.5]{\Large $\gamma$};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

This produces the following output:

[image: Wrong]

If I change the `end angle`, the situation is not very different. These are the outputs with angles respectively with `end angle=180` and `end angle=360`.

[image: wrong_180]

[image: wrong_360]

How can I fix the problem?

Comment: Welcome to TeX:SE! Try to use `\draw[line width=2pt] (\radi,0)   arc[start angle=0,end angle=90,radius=\radi]; 
\node[above right] at (45:\radi) {\Large $\gamma$};` instead of `\draw[line width=2pt] (\radi,0)   arc[start angle=0,end angle=90,radius=\radi] node[pos=0.5]{\Large $\gamma$}; `

Comment: Welcome. // Just a hint, don’t see without compiling, what‘s going on. arc is tricky: first you move to the starting point, next you move along the arc, starting at start angle. I.e. the center is somewhere to the left. // If you just need to place letter gamma, use a separate \node statement, i.e. outside your draw command (not necessary, but to make it more evident ).

Comment: @MS-SPO and Zarko Thank you: I used this way to overcome the problem and this is fine. Nevertheless, I would like to know why tikz does not place nodes correctly on the arc, while usually it does on segments, graphs of functions and so on.

Answer (score 1):

Some observations: looks like you use pgfplots just to draw the axis, which I consider a kind of intended lazyness in this context ... you can draw them as nicely with pure Tikz, even with less code.

How did I see it? Well, commenting out all "unnecessary" packages gave an error quickly: *environment axis undefined*.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a4paper, top=2cm, bottom=3cm, left=2.5cm, right=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{amssymb}
%\usepackage{tikz-cd}% <<<<<<<<<
%\usepackage{pgfplots}% <<<<<<<<<
\usepackage{tikz,tikz-3dplot}  
%\usetikzlibrary{arrows,decorations.markings,intersections,patterns,shadings,calc,shapes,positioning,  pgfplots.fillbetween, shapes.geometric}% <<<<<<<<<
%\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}% <<<<<<<<<
\definecolor{azz}{RGB}{175,238,238}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[>=latex,
]
\newcommand\xmi{-1.2};
\newcommand\xma{1.2};
\newcommand\yma{1.2};
\newcommand{\radi}{1};
  \begin{axis}[% <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
    clip=false,
    width=16cm,
    axis equal image,
    xmin=\xmi, xmax=\xma,
    ymin=\xmi, ymax=\xma,
    axis lines=middle,
    no markers,
    xtick={0},
    ytick={0},
    xticklabels={,,},
    yticklabels={,,},
    extra x ticks={0},
    extra x tick style={xticklabel style={anchor=north east}},
    extra x tick label={\Large $0$},
    xlabel={\Large $\mathbb{R}$},
    ylabel={\Large $i \mathbb{R}$},
    axis on top
    ]
  \draw[fill=azz!100!white, opacity=0.7] (0,0) circle (\radi) ;
\draw[line width=2pt] (\radi,0)   arc[start angle=0,end angle=90,radius=\radi] node[pos=0.5]{\Large $\gamma$};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

You CAN mix pgfplots and tikz, WHEN taking care of interoperability, see ch. 4.26 in pgfplots. Don't know if you did this from your question. If not, this is probably the root cause for "unexpected behaviour".

It's easy to draw x- and y-axis as you need with Tikz. Didn't check, whether or not the node is placed correctly, then. Here it looks like pgfplots assigns a radius of r=2 (or more) to your arc wrt the node at `[pos=.5]`.

Unfortunatey I can't read from your question, what els you have in mind, looking at the set of packages you somehow want to use.

---

**Verified**: That's the problem, the way you mix pgfplots and tikz. Commenting out the axis statement results in:

[image: result2]

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[>=latex,
]
\newcommand\xmi{-1.2};
\newcommand\xma{1.2};
\newcommand\yma{1.2};
\newcommand{\radi}{1};
%  \begin{axis}[
%    clip=false,
%    width=16cm,
%    axis equal image,
%    xmin=\xmi, xmax=\xma,
%    ymin=\xmi, ymax=\xma,
%    axis lines=middle,
%    no markers,
%    xtick={0},
%    ytick={0},
%    xticklabels={,,},
%    yticklabels={,,},
%    extra x ticks={0},
%    extra x tick style={xticklabel style={anchor=north east}},
%    extra x tick label={\Large $0$},
%    xlabel={\Large $\mathbb{R}$},
%    ylabel={\Large $i \mathbb{R}$},
%    axis on top
%    ]
  \draw[fill=azz!100!white, opacity=0.7] (0,0) circle (\radi) ;
\draw[line width=2pt] (\radi,0)   arc[start angle=0,end angle=90,radius=\radi] node[pos=0.5]{\Large $\gamma$};
%\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```